# url rewrite using querystring

Tags: .net, iis

I am trying to configure a url rewrite with querystring within web.confg.

What I am trying to rewrite is:

> /organising-a-conference/find-a-venue-or-service/enquiry-shortlist/site/pdfs/**25c50afc-4b73-4438-82c7-c03d13e8a953**.pdf?Action=download

to

> /site/pdfs/**25c50afc-4b73-4438-82c7-c03d13e8a953**.pdf?Action=download

keeping the variable Guid in bold in the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `rewrites` section of your **web.config**:

```
<add name="RwName"
     virtualUrl="^~/organising-a-conference/find-a-venue-or-service/enquiry-shortlist/site/pdfs/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).pdf?Action=download"
     regexOptions="CultureInvariant"
     ignoreCase="true"
     destinationUrl="~/site/pdfs/$1.pdf?Action=download" />
```

Of course, you can also validate the **GUID** by making the **RegEx** more specific.